# Published Blazor WASM JSON not parsing GoDaddy CPANEL

Tags: blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly, godaddy-api

When I run my application in development it works just fine connecting to my GoDaddy cPanel MySQL. However once I publish my folder file and try to run my domain and call my get request it returns a Blazor page and not raw data. Causing the JSON not being able to parse error. I have added cors to see if that was the problem. I added api routing in my htaccess file to see if that was the issue. At this point i'm lost it's my first published website and I dont want to have to hard code over 3,000 products.

Error:

```
`blazor.webassembly.js:1 crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: ExpectedStartOfValueNotFound, < Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.
System.Text.Json.JsonException: ExpectedStartOfValueNotFound, < Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.
 ---> System.Text.Json.JsonReaderException: ExpectedStartOfValueNotFound, < LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.
   at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowJsonReaderException(Utf8JsonReader& , ExceptionResource , Byte , ReadOnlySpan`1 )
   at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ConsumeValue(Byte )
   at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ReadFirstToken(Byte )
   at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ReadSingleSegment()
   at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.Read()
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1[[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[GoDaddyMySql.Shared.Product, GoDaddyMySql.Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].ReadCore(Utf8JsonReader& , JsonSerializerOptions , ReadStack& )
   Exception_EndOfInnerExceptionStack
   at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ReThrowWithPath(ReadStack& , JsonReaderException )
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1[[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[GoDaddyMySql.Shared.Product, GoDaddyMySql.Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].ReadCore(Utf8JsonReader& , JsonSerializerOptions , ReadStack& )
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadCore[List`1](JsonConverter , Utf8JsonReader& , JsonSerializerOptions , ReadStack& )
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadCore[List`1](JsonReaderState& , Boolean , ReadOnlySpan`1 , JsonSerializerOptions , ReadStack& , JsonConverter )
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ContinueDeserialize[List`1](ReadBufferState& , JsonReaderState& , ReadStack& , JsonConverter , JsonSerializerOptions )
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.<ReadAllAsync>d__65`1[[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[GoDaddyMySql.Shared.Product, GoDaddyMySql.Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].MoveNext()
   at System.Net.Http.Json.HttpContentJsonExtensions.<ReadFromJsonAsyncCore>d__4`1[[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[GoDaddyMySql.Shared.Product, GoDaddyMySql.Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].MoveNext()
   at System.Net.Http.Json.HttpClientJsonExtensions.<GetFromJsonAsyncCore>d__13`1[[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[GoDaddyMySql.Shared.Product, GoDaddyMySql.Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].MoveNext()
   at GoDaddyMySql.Client.Pages.FetchData.OnInitializedAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task , ComponentState )`

Client Side : `@page "/fetchdata"
@inject HttpClient httpClient
@using System.Net.Http
@using System.Net.Http.Json
@using System.Collections.Generic
@using GoDaddyMySql.Shared;



<h1>Product List</h1>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Active</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var product in Products)
        {
        <tr>
            <td>@product.Id</td>
            <td>@product.Name</td>
            <td>@product.Description</td>
            <td>@product.Active</td>
        </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

@code{

    List<Product> Products = new List<Product>();
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Products = await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Product>>("TestConnection");
    }
}}`

Server Side: `using GoDaddyMySql.Shared;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace GoDaddyMySql.Server.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class TestConnectionController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _config;

        public TestConnectionController(IConfiguration config)
        {
            _config = config;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public List<Product> GetAllProducts()
        {
            List<Product> products = new List<Product>();

            using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(_config.GetConnectionString("MySqlConnection")))
            {
                string query = "SELECT Id, Name, Description, Active FROM Product";

                MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);

                connection.Open(); // Open the connection

                using (MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        Product product = new Product
                        {
                            Id = reader.GetInt32("Id"),
                            Name = reader.GetString("Name"),
                            Description = reader.GetString("Description"),
                            Active = reader.GetBoolean("Active")
                        };

                        products.Add(product);
                    }
                }

                connection.Close(); // Close the connection
            }

            return products;
        }

    }
}`

`AppSettings : {
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MySqlConnection": "Server=xxx.xxx.xx.xxx;Port=xxxx;Database=databasename;Uid=username;Pwd=password;"
  }
}`
```